# JDeveloper IntegratedWebLogicServer not able to build default domain

Tags: jdeveloper, weblogic11g

I am trying to run the JDeveloper Integrated Weblogic server (11.1.1.5) on Windows 7 x64 and keep running into this error from within JDeveloper:

```
[Starting Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer]
#### Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer could not be started: Error starting Server Instance.
```

I found this in the createDefaultDomain.log file:

```
Log File:      C:\Users\mologan\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.5.37.60.13\o.j2ee.adrs\CreateDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_11.1.1.5.0_GENERIC_110409.0025.6013
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\mologan\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.5.37.60.13\DefaultDomain

"C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\mologan\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.5.37.60.13\o.j2ee.adrs\CreateDefaultDomain.py"
Process started
Elapsed time:  94 ms
```

When I try to run this command from the command line I get the following:

```
C:\Users\mologan>"C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\mologan\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.5.37.60.13\o.j2ee.adrs\CreateDefaultDomain.py"

CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1/modules/oracle.jrf_11.1.1/jrf-wlstman.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\lib\ADF-SH~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\lib\ADFSCR~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\lib\mdswlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\AUDITW~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\IGFWLS~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\jps-wlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\jrf-wlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OAMAP_~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OAMAUT~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\ossoiap.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OSSOIA~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OVDWLS~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\SSLCON~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\wsm-wlst.jar

PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\syswow64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\ant\\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8 Your environment has been set.

CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1/modules/oracle.jrf_11.1.1/jrf-wlstman.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\lib\ADF-SH~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\lib\ADFSCR~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\lib\mdswlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\AUDITW~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\IGFWLS~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\jps-wlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\jrf-wlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OAMAP_~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OAMAUT~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\ossoiap.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OSSOIA~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\OVDWLS~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\SSLCON~1.JAR;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\common\wlst\RESOUR~1\wsm-wlst.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\utils\config\10.3\config-launch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbytools.jar;;
Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Error:  ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set.

Exiting WebLogic Scripting Tool.

C:\Users\mologan>
```

Has anyone seen this type of error before? I have no idea how to fix it and its getting really frustrating. All help is much appreciated!

Cheers,

Morris

Answer (score 0):

Open CreateDefaultDomain.py file and set ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD.

```
import os
os.putenv('ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD', 'welcome1')
if not 'ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD' in os.environ:
  print("Error:  ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set.")
  exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

Domain creation fails after installing on new Windows version (7338577, 7339920, 8654914)
When JDeveloper is installed on a newly released Windows version, it is possible that Jython, which is used by Oracle WebLogic Server's script tool, does not recognize the Windows version and instead assumes that it is running in a Linux environment.

This causes domain creation to fail with the following error in CreateDefaultDomain.log:

```
wlst > Failed to get environment, environ will be empty: (0, 'Failed to / 
execute command ([\'sh\', \'-c\', \'env\']): java.io.IOException: Cannot run / 
program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file / 
specified')/ 
@ wlst > Error:  ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD environment variable not set.
```

The workaround is to obtain a patch for jython-modules.jar, or to run on a supported version of Windows.

Original source:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/knownissues-097654.html#dep1

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JDeveloper 12.2.1.3.0.
Have the same problem, and all I had to to is exit the JDeploper, kill the Java process in the Task Manager, and restarting JDev again.